# Linking two excel sheets and joining data

Tags: excel

Regularly i need to link two excel sheets together. I have no problems doing that using excel and microsoft query. I get the sheets from vendors, they contain referencenumbers, prices and codes.

I link the 2 sheets with the reference numbers that are listed in both the sheets.

But the one of the sheets i got this time have little different reference numbers than the other. All the numbers are the same BUT start with a character "K" in front of it.

```
Sheet1: 
[ol]
[li]2255674489925[/li]
[li]1255639784411[/li]
[li]5669215004789[/li]
[/ol]

Sheet2: 
[ol]
[li]K2255674489925[/li]
[li]K1255639784411[/li]
[li]K5669215004789[/li]
[/ol]
```

The sheets contain around 40000 rows so i cannot manually delete all the characters.

I tried to do this with the % wildcard but no succes.

```
SELECT `Blad1$`.ref, `Blad1$`.prijs, `Blad1$`.korting, `Blad2$`.ref2, `Blad2$`.winst
FROM `C:\Users\Nibor\Desktop\test.xlsx`.`Blad1$` `Blad1$`, `C:\Users\Nibor\Desktop    \test.xlsx`.`Blad2$` `Blad2$`
WHERE `Blad2$`.ref2 = `Blad1$`.%ref
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do a Search&Replace for letter K in the whole Workbook?

```
Search for: K

Replace with: (nothing)
```

Should sort out your problem....